# Automator service to look up words works with Latin characters but not Chinese characters

Tags: applescript, automator, javascript

The following Automator script is supposed to open a Chrome tab and look up a Chinese word.

The service opens the Chrome tab when Latin characters are chosen, but mysteriously fails to open a tab when Chinese characters are chosen.

**Works**

1. Open https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_classifiers.
2. Highlight Latin character.
3. Run service.

**Fails**

1. Open https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_classifiers.
2. Highlight Chinese character.
3. Run service.

**Run JavaScript**

```
function run(input, parameters) {

    var trimmedInput = input[0].replace(/\s/g, '');
    return trimmedInput
    
}
```

**Run AppleScript**

```
on run {input, parameters}
        
    return "http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/search/?searchtype=2&text=" & input
    
end run
```

**Run AppleScript**

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set curTabIndex to active tab index of front window
                
        open location input
        
        set active tab index of first window to curTabIndex
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Why a **Run JavaScript** _action_ and two **Run AppleScript** _actions_ when it can be done in a single **Run AppleScript** _action_!? Also, `open location` is a part of **Standard Additions**, not **Google Chrome**. So, if you want to open a `URL` in **Google Chrome** then set the `URL` of the `active tab` to the target **URL**.  BTW This works for me coded using a single **Run AppleScript** _action_ if I select the first Chinese character in the URL you linked, it goes to `http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/search/?searchtype=2&text=把` and changes to `.../dictionary/characters/821/`

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for the help. new to apple script and automator, so not sure why it was split into three actions. you're saying it fails if split into three actions but works if consolidated into one action?

Comment: @user3439894 also how do you turn the javascript into apple script? thanks for your help!

Comment: RE: "you're saying it fails if split into three actions but works if consolidated into one action?" -- No, Im not saying it fails with the three _actions_, you are. Isn't that why you posted the question?  I didn't test with the three _actions_, just wrote _code_ of one **Run AppleScript** _action_ and it worked. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* combines the three **Automator** *actions* shown in your OP into one **Run AppleScript** *action*.

Selecting the first Chinese character, from the link in your OP, and running the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* it worked for me by opening a new *tab* to the target **URL**.

- Note that as coded it assumes **Google Chrome** is already running with at least one *window* already opened and it further assumes you are selecting the *text* in the *active tab* of the *front window*, otherwise the coding of the *tell block* for **Google Chrome** needs to be modified.
- The *script* uses `AppleScript's text item delimiters` to do the same thing as: `.replace(/\s/g, '')`

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set searchString to input as text
    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
    set searchString to text items of searchString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set searchString to searchString as text
    
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell front window
            set curTabIndex to active tab index
            set URL of (make new tab) to ¬
                "http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/search/?searchtype=2&text=" & ¬
                searchString
            set active tab index to curTabIndex
        end tell
    end tell
    
end run
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

Comment: i tried amending this script to click on a button on a web page, but it seems to fail. if you have time, it would be great to get your advice: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402205/automator-script-to-click-button-on-web-page-generates-the-operation-couldn-t-b