# Automator script to click button on web page generates “The operation couldn’t be completed." error

Tags: applescript, automator, google-chrome

The AppleScript below is supposed to click the first element with the magnifier class on a predefined web page.

The script runs successfully if you comment out the JavaScript line, `do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('magnifier')[0].click();"`

From the Chrome console, this line of JavaScript executes successfully.

But if you include the JavaScript line, the following error occurs:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “The operation
> couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.Automator error -212.)”

Anyone have any ideas what the problem could be?

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set searchString to input as text
    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
    set searchString to text items of searchString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set searchString to searchString as text
    
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell front window
            set curTabIndex to active tab index
            set URL of (make new tab) to ¬
                "https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php?searchMode=C&word=" & ¬
                searchString
            set active tab index to curTabIndex
            
            delay 2.0
            
            do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('magnifier')[0].click();"
        end tell
    end tell
    
end run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do JavaScript` is for **Safari**. `execute javascript` is for **Google Chrome**, e.g.:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window to ¬
    execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('magnifier')[0].click();"
```

That said, where you have it placed in the *script* may not be where you really want it.

Here is some *example* **AppleScript** *code* run in **Script Editor** with **Google Chrome** opened with at least one *window*.

It waits for the target **URL** to finish loading before clicking the magnifying glass and then sets the `active tab` back to the original *active tab*.

```applescript
set input to {"桿"}

set searchString to input as text

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
set searchString to text items of searchString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set searchString to searchString as text

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell front window
        set curTabIndex to active tab index
        set URL of (make new tab) to ¬
            "https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php?searchMode=C&word=" & ¬
            searchString
        repeat until (loading of active tab is false)
            delay 1
        end repeat
        tell active tab to execute javascript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('magnifier')[0].click();"
        delay 0.5
        set active tab index to curTabIndex
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Update to address comment.**

The same conditions mentioned above applies to this *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set input to {"桿"}

set searchString to input as text

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
set searchString to text items of searchString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set searchString to searchString as text

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell front window
        set curTabIndex to active tab index
        set URL of (make new tab) to ¬
            "https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php?searchMode=C&word=" & ¬
            searchString
        set active tab index to curTabIndex
        repeat until (loading of last tab is false)
            delay 1
        end repeat
        tell last tab to execute javascript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('magnifier')[0].click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

Comment: thanks so much again! this worked. is there anyway to have the javascript execute without switching tabs?

Comment: put another way, is it possible for applescript to run on tabs that aren't active?

Comment: @Crashalot, See _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ under **Update to address comment.** in the updated answer.  Remember this is just _example code_, if need be it can be written differently to target a different tab by programmatically determining the target _tab_ and use _variables_ as necessary, ect.

Comment: this worked! you're amazing. thanks so much for your prompt responses. :)